# Keep the true ARRAY OBJECT between Javascript -to- PHP via Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays, json

I want to post Javascript Array Object via Ajax to PHP. Then at PHP end, i still want to use that object as an true Array. Below is my approach so far still not successful in terms of using the incoming object as an `Array` at PHP side. I can just parse it as the `string`.

Javascript:

```
var myObj = { 
    fred: { apples: 2, oranges: 4, bananas: 7, melons: 0 }, 
    mary: { apples: 0, oranges: 10, bananas: 0, melons: 0 }, 
    sarah: { apples: 0, oranges: 0, bananas: 0, melons: 5 } 
}
```

Then, Javascript/JQuery to send via AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { "data" : JSON.stringify(myObj) }
}).success(function( response ) {
    alert(response);
});
```

Then parse at PHP:

```
$data = json_decode( $_POST["data"] );
echo json_encode( $data["fred"] );
echo json_encode( $data["fred"]["apples"] );
echo json_encode( $data["fred"]->apples );
echo json_encode( $data[1] );
```

- Any of above `echo` returns blanks, back to the browser.

But when i:

```
$data = json_decode( $_POST["data"] );
$to_string = print_r( $data, true ); //<-- Used these instead
echo json_encode( $to_string ); //<-- Used these instead
```

.. it returns following big strings back to the browser:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [fred] => stdClass Object
        (
            [apples] => 2
            [oranges] => 4
            [bananas] => 7
            [melons] => 0
        )

    [mary] => stdClass Object
        (
            [apples] => 0
            [oranges] => 10
            [bananas] => 0
            [melons] => 0
        )

    [sarah] => stdClass Object
        (
            [apples] => 0
            [oranges] => 0
            [bananas] => 0
            [melons] => 5
        )
)
```

- So seems data is there, but how can i parse this data as in the proper truely `ARRAY` manner at `PHP` end, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass second argument as `true`, it will convert data in array

```
$data = json_decode( $_POST["data"] , true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass `true` as an argument to json_decode to return an associative array instead of an object:

```
json_decode($string, true);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php